# Python Pandas: list columns with the same values for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks next:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan],
        'col3': ['aa','b','cc','d','ff'],
        'col4': [4, 6, 3, 4, np.nan]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']) 

 col1  col2 col3  col4
0    a   1.0   aa   4.0
1    b   2.0    b   6.0
2    c   3.0   cc   3.0
3    d   4.0    d   4.0
4    e   NaN   ff   NaN
```

I'd like to find all columns with the same value for each row.
So the result should look something like this:

```
Row 1: col1 eq col3;
Row 2: col2 eq col4;
Row 3: col1 eq col3; col2 eq col4
```

Dataframe have string and num columns, so maybe it will be worth to convert everything to str.
NaN data values should be ignored, as there are a lot of missing =)

Many thanks

Comment: I second @not_a_robot's comment.  I can't make sense of your request and stated result.

Comment: Reposting the comment I deleted: Can you clarify just how `col1` equals `col3` at row 3 (index 2)? I just see `c` for col1 and `cc` for col3, which technically aren't equal (although `c` is a proper subset of `cc`). It seems like the indexing shown in your desired output is off...

Comment: I was counting rows from 0. My bad, I should use 'index' instead.

Values 'c' and 'cc' should not be treated as equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another answer I came up with. I didn't know what to output for a row where none of the columns have equal values, so I just skip that row in the output. Also added a row where many columns have the same value to show what happens there.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 1],
        'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 1],
        'col3': ['aa','b','cc','d','ff', 1],
        'col4': [4, 6, 3, 4, np.nan, 1],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']) 

for row in df.itertuples():
    values = list(set(row))  # Get the unique values in the row
    equal_columns = []  # Keep track of column names that are the same
    for v in values:
        # Column names that have this value
        columns = [df.columns[i-1] for i, x in enumerate(row) if x == v]
        if len(columns) > 1:
            # If more than 1 column with this value, append to the list
            equal_columns.append(' eq '.join(columns))
    if len(equal_columns) > 0:
        # We have at least 1 set of equal columns
        equal_columns.sort()  # So we always start printing in lexicographic order
        print('Row {0}: {1};'.format(row.Index, '; '.join(equal_columns)))
```

Give me the output,

```
Row 1: col1 eq col3;
Row 2: col2 eq col4;
Row 3: col1 eq col3; col2 eq col4;
Row 5: col1 eq col2 eq col3 eq col4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a for-loop solution you can use... Perhaps piRSquared can come up with a better, pure-pandas solution. This should work in a pinch.

```
row_eqs = {}

# For each row
for idx in df.index:
    # Make a set of all "column equivalencies" for each row
    row_eqs[idx] = set()
    for col in df.columns:
        # Look at all of the other columns that aren't `col`        
        other_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != col]
        # Column value
        col_row_value = df.loc[idx, col]
        for c in other_cols:
            # Other column row value
            c_row_value = df.loc[idx, c]
            if c_row_value == col_row_value:
                # Just make your strings here since lists and sets aren't hashable
                eq = ' eq '.join(sorted((c, col)))
                row_eqs[idx].add(eq)
```

Print the result:

```
for idx in row_eqs:
    if row_eqs[idx]:
        print('Row %d: %s' % (idx, '; '.join(row_eqs[idx])))

Row 1: col1 eq col3
Row 2: col2 eq col4
Row 3: col1 eq col3; col2 eq col4
```

Edit: A slightly faster way of doing things, by hard-coding the total number of column combination pairs beforehand:

```
column_combos = {combo for combo in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2)}

for idx in df.index:
    row_eqs[idx] = set()
    for col1, col2 in column_combos:
        col1_value = df.loc[idx, col1]
        col2_value = df.loc[idx, col2]
        if col1_value == col2_value:
                eq = ' eq '.join(sorted((col1, col2)))
                row_eqs[idx].add(eq)
```

I don't know just how big your data are, but this latter solution was about 25% faster than the former.

Comment: I'd likely go down the path of trying to turn things into sets and using `<=` to determine whether it's a subset.  But I won't waste the time without clarification.

Comment: Thanks!
Dataset is not huge (~700Mb). However, a number of columns with the same value per row is unknown.@piRSquared thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have the following DF:

```
In [1]: from numpy import nan
   ...: from itertools import combinations
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(
   ...: {'col1': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
   ...:  'col2': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: nan},
   ...:  'col3': {0: 'aa', 1: 'b', 2: 'cc', 3: 'd', 4: 'ff'},
   ...:  'col4': {0: 4.0, 1: 6.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 4: nan},
   ...:  'col5': {0: nan, 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: nan, 4: 'e'}})
   ...:

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  col1  col2 col3  col4 col5
0    a   1.0   aa   4.0  NaN
1    b   2.0    b   6.0    b
2    c   3.0   cc   3.0    c
3    d   4.0    d   4.0  NaN
4    e   NaN   ff   NaN    e
```

Let's generate a query with all combinations of columns of the **same dtype**:

```
In [3]: qry = \
   ...: (df.dtypes
   ...:    .reset_index(name='type')
   ...:    .groupby('type')['index']
   ...:    .apply(lambda x:
   ...:             '\n'.join(['{0[0]}_{0[1]} = ({0[0]} == {0[1]})'.format(tup, tup)
   ...:                          for tup in combinations(x, 2)]))
   ...:    .str.cat(sep='\n')
   ...: )

In [5]: print(qry)
col2_col4 = (col2 == col4)
col1_col3 = (col1 == col3)
col1_col5 = (col1 == col5)
col3_col5 = (col3 == col5)
```

now we can do this:

```
In [6]: cols = df.columns.tolist()

In [7]: (df.eval(qry, inplace=False)
   ...:    .drop(cols, 1)
   ...:    .apply(lambda r: ';'.join(r.index[r].tolist()).replace('_',' == '), axis=1)
   ...: )
Out[7]:
0
1    col1 == col3;col1 == col5;col3 == col5
2                 col2 == col4;col1 == col5
3                 col2 == col4;col1 == col3
4                              col1 == col5
dtype: object
```

Explanation:

```
In [9]: df.eval(qry, inplace=False).drop(cols, 1)
Out[9]:
  col2_col4 col1_col3 col1_col5 col3_col5
0     False     False     False     False
1     False      True      True      True
2      True     False      True     False
3      True      True     False     False
4     False     False      True     False
```

Answer (score 0):

An other efficient way :

```
a=df.values
equality=(a[:,newaxis,:]==a[:,:,newaxis])
match = row,col1,col2 = np.triu(equality,1).nonzero()
```

`match` is now :

```
(array([1, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([2, 3, 2, 3], dtype=int64))
```

Then pretty printing :

```
dfc=df.columns    
for i,r in enumerate(row):
    print( str(r),' : ',str(dfc[col1[i]]),'=',str(dfc[col2[i]]))
```

For :

```
1  :  col1 = col3
2  :  col2 = col4
3  :  col1 = col3
3  :  col2 = col4
```